# Examples of non-abelian groups under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, noncommutative-algebra

I tried to find non-abelian groups under addition, but failed. It seems to me that all number sets hold addition under a commutative law. What are some examples of non-abelian groups under addition?

Comment: For a group it doesn‘t matter what you call the group operation. We might call it addition or multiplication because of analogies or for psychological reasons.

Comment: What do you mean by "under addition"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan UNDER ADDITION means the binary operation should be addition.

Comment: What does that mean? Do you mean it should be addition of natural numbers? Real numbers? All of those groups are abelian, so their subgroups are also abelian.

Answer (score 6):

Usually when we use the word "addition" it is for an operation that is commutative. So almost by definition, you will have a hard time finding a non-abelian group whose operation is called "addition."

Comment: Precisely. Typically, noncommutative laws of composition, are written multiplicatively, so that we are used to expecting “$+$” to refer to commutative laws only. This is more a matter of convention than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

A group involves a set and a binary operation on them, satisfying some conditions. Most common examples are set of numbers with addition as the binary operation. This is commutative. And so any  subgroup of numbers under addition will be commutative (abelian) too.

So what you are expecting  is a group on some other set where the binary operation is  NOT commutative. There are so many sets with so many operations and it is difficult to come up with names for those operations.

(When coffee and sugar are put together in a cup  we call it adding sugar to coffee. When a book is revised for the second edition the author may "add" a chapter to it. )
But conventionally the word "addition" is used in algebra for commutative binary operations.

Consider all functions of the form $ax+b$ with $a, b$ real numbers and $a\neq 0$.   SUch collections do not form a group under addition ($3x-5$ and $-3x-5$ when "addded" gives the function $0x-5$ which is not in our set).

However this collection forms a group when we define "composition of functions" as the binary operation. Composition 
$(ax+b)\circ (cx+d) = cax + bc+d$. This is not equal to
$(cx+d)\circ (ax+b)$, hence not abelian. (Check it).
The inverse function for $ax+b$  would be $\frac 1a x -\frac ba$.

Comment: @P Vanchinathan  Is it possible to define such an operation over a set of $2^{128}$ integers?

Comment: @viyps: When we say integers, we almost always mean that set where the operation is usual addition of numbers. For a finite set it means a variation like addition modulo some N. All these are commutative operations. So a more meaningful question would be " Is there a set having $2^{128}$ elements which under suitable binary operation is a non-coommutative group.?". The answer for THIS question is yes.